# broadleaf: moving to mysql - getting error

Tags: mysql, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to move from hsql to mysql db for demosite. I have followed instructions mentioned in the broadleaf site, but i am facing below error

```
Buildfile: B:\dummy\eclipse-my-workspace\DemoSite\site\build.xml
tomcat:
[artifact:mvn] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[artifact:mvn] [INFO]                                                                         
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Building site 1.0
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Downloading: repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.15-bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.pom
[artifact:mvn] [WARNING] The POM for mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.15-bin is missing, no dependency information available
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Downloading: repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.15-bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
Buildfile: B:\dummy\eclipse-my-workspace\DemoSite\site\build.xml
tomcat:
[artifact:mvn] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[artifact:mvn] [INFO]                                                                         
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Building site 1.0
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Downloading: repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.15-bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.pom
[artifact:mvn] [WARNING] The POM for mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.15-bin is missing, no dependency information available
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Downloading: repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.15-bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Total time: 8.661 s
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-24T18:57:34+05:30
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/31M
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project site: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:site:war:1.0: Failure to find mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.15-bin in nexus.broadleafcommerce.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of public snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell with the little information you have provided but seems like an issue with your root pom.xml where you have specified the dependency for mysql-connector. Refer to the latest broadleaf documentation for switching to mysql - http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/getting-started-tutorials/switch-to-mysql-tutorial

And then do a maven install on the root project you should be good to go then.

Answer (score 0):

The error says Failure to find mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.15-bin jar by the application.

I believe, you need to add a dependency of mysql connector in the root pom.xml. Once the build has been made, just make sure the mysql connector were downloaded by the maven tool in the tomcat / bin folder.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Sridhar C